# Apache Basic authentication based on AuthUserFile is ignored, when mod_auth_radius.c is enabled

Tags: apache-2.4, redhat, radius

I hope you can help me with my problem.

I initially had a vhost config with Basic Authentication with "AuthUserFile" which works fine.
Now I wanted to use Radius for certain sites and installed "mod_auth_radius" according to the instructions. Since then, the other sites try also authentication via radius instead of "AuthUserFile", although no radius is configured there.

```
[001mgm ~]$ grep LoadModule /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf
# have to place corresponding `LoadModule' lines at this location so the
# LoadModule foo_module modules/mod_foo.so
LoadModule radius_auth_module /usr/lib64/httpd/modules/mod_auth_radius.so
[001mgm ~]$
[001mgm ~]$
[001mgm ~]$ sudo httpd -M | egrep '(rad|basic|core|file)'  core_module (static)
 radius_auth_module (shared)
 auth_basic_module (shared)
 authn_core_module (shared)
 authn_file_module (shared)
 authz_core_module (shared)
 authz_groupfile_module (shared)
```

Here the 1st vhos1-site.conf with AuthUserFile authentication

```
# domain name
Define SERVER_NAME site1.x.x.x
Define ROOTDIR /..../site1
Define LOCATION site1

# HTPASSWD File
<AuthnProviderAlias file allowed-users>
        AuthUserFile ${ROOTDIR}/.htpasswd
</AuthnProviderAlias>
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName ${SERVER_NAME}
        ServerAdmin ${SERVER_ADMIN}

        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/${SERVER_NAME}/access.log combined
        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/${SERVER_NAME}/error.log

        RedirectMatch (.*) https://${SERVER_NAME}$1
</VirtualHost>
<VirtualHost *:443>
        ServerName ${SERVER_NAME}
        ServerAdmin ${SERVER_ADMIN}

        DocumentRoot ${ROOTDIR}

        LogLevel debug rewrite:trace6
        #LogLevel error ssl:warn
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/${SERVER_NAME}/access.log combined
        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/${SERVER_NAME}/error.log

        SSLEngine on
        SSLCertificateFile ${SSL_CERT}
        SSLCertificateKeyFile ${SSL_KEY}

        SSLProtocol all -SSLv2 -SSLv3
        SSLHonorCipherOrder on
        SSLCipherSuite @SECLEVEL=3:kEECDH:kEDH:kPSK:kDHEPSK:kECDHEPSK:-kRSA:-aDSS:-AES128:-SHA256:-3DES:!DES:!RC4:!RC2:!IDEA:-SEED:!eNULL:!aNULL:-SHA1:!MD5:-SHA384:-CAMELLIA:-ARIA:-AESCCM8
        SSLCompression Off

        <Directory ${ROOTDIR}>
                Options Indexes MultiViews FollowSymlinks SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
                DirectoryIndex index.php
                <RequireAll>
                        Require ip ....
                        Require ip ....
                        Require ip ....
                </RequireAll>
                SSLRequireSSL
                AuthType Basic
                AuthName "Auth for ${Location}"
                AuthBasicProvider allowed-users
                Require valid-user
        </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

And the 2nd vhost-site2.conf with radius authentication:

```
# domain name
Define SERVER_NAME site2.x.x.x
Define ROOTDIR /..../site2
Define LOCATION site2

# RADIUS
Define RADIUS_HOST x.x.x.x:1812
<IfModule mod_auth_radius.c>
        AddRadiusAuth ${RADIUS_HOST} xxxxsecretxxxx 5:3
        AddRadiusCookieValid 5
</IfModule>

<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName ${SERVER_NAME}
        ServerAdmin ${SERVER_ADMIN}

        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/${SERVER_NAME}/access.log combined
        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/${SERVER_NAME}/error.log

        RedirectMatch (.*) https://${SERVER_NAME}$1
</VirtualHost>
<VirtualHost *:443>
        ServerName ${SERVER_NAME}
        ServerAdmin ${SERVER_ADMIN}

        DocumentRoot ${ROOTDIR}

        LogLevel debug rewrite:trace6
        #LogLevel error ssl:warn
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/${SERVER_NAME}/access.log combined
        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/${SERVER_NAME}/error.log

        SSLEngine on
        SSLCertificateFile ${SSL_CERT}
        SSLCertificateKeyFile ${SSL_KEY}

        SSLProtocol all -SSLv2 -SSLv3
        SSLHonorCipherOrder on
        SSLCipherSuite @SECLEVEL=3:kEECDH:kEDH:kPSK:kDHEPSK:kECDHEPSK:-kRSA:-aDSS:-AES128:-SHA256:-3DES:!DES:!RC4:!RC2:!IDEA:-SEED:!eNULL:!aNULL:-SHA1:!MD5:-SHA384:-CAMELLIA:-ARIA:-AESCCM8
        SSLCompression Off

        <Directory ${ROOTDIR}>
                Options Indexes MultiViews FollowSymlinks SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
                DirectoryIndex index.php
                <RequireAll>
                        Require ip ....
                        Require ip ....
                        Require ip ....
                </RequireAll>
                SSLRequireSSL
                AuthType Basic
                AuthName "Auth for ${Location}"
                AuthBasicProvider radius
                AuthBasicAuthoritative Off
                AuthRadiusAuthoritative on
                AuthRadiusActive On
                AddRadiusCallingStationID ${Location}
                AuthRadiusCookieValid 15
                AuthRadiusDebug on
                Require valid-user
        </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

The Logs show (debug) following:

```
AH02034: Initial (No.1) HTTPS request received for child 146 (server site1.x.x.x.x:443)
[Thu Jul 20 15:31:44.459561 2023] [:debug] [pid 10342:tid 139805463598848] mod_auth_radius.c(1308): Radius Auth for: site1.x.x.x.x requests / : file=/.../site1/
[Thu Jul 20 15:31:44.459587 2023] [:debug] [pid 10342:tid 139805463598848] mod_auth_radius.c(1338): No cookie found.  Trying RADIUS authentication.
[Thu Jul 20 15:31:44.460186 2023] [:debug] [pid 10342:tid 139805463598848] mod_auth_radius.c(1037): Sending packet on x.x.x.x:1812
[Thu Jul 20 15:31:44.516263 2023] [:debug] [pid 10342:tid 139805463598848] mod_auth_radius.c(1196): RADIUS authentication failed for user "user_in_AuthFile"
[Thu Jul 20 15:31:44.516284 2023] [:debug] [pid 10342:tid 139805463598848] mod_auth_radius.c(1355): RADIUS authentication for user=user_in_AuthFile password=yyyyyy failed
[Thu Jul 20 15:31:44.516293 2023] [:debug] [pid 10342:tid 139805463598848] mod_auth_radius.c(1361): Sending failure message to user=user_in_AuthFile
```

As you can see, even radius is not configured i vhost-site1.conf, authentication is checked via radius and not to the local file.

When i disabled "radius_auth_module" and restart apache, authentication on site1 works again.

What's wrong with my vhosts-config or httpd.conf?

Many thanks for any hints or suggestions